# SQL SERVER number of .bak files created

Tags: sql-server, vsdb

I am wondering where (if possible) you can configure the number of backups, for a particular SQL Server database, are kept within the system backups folder.  i.e. it should "clean up" old backups automatically (if possible).

Furthermore, I have a VS2010 Database project, and I can specify that I want backups to be created upon deployment, but again I was hoping there was a way to control HOW many backups it will create, and if possible to clean up old backups.

I know its a loaded question, but there must be an easy way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: You should ask this on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) where the SQL Server DBA's hang out - they will know this inside and out ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controlling when and how many backups will be created, and when the old backups are deleted is easy when you backup your databases with [SQL Server's Maintenance Plans](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189953.aspx).

There is a task named "[Maintenance Cleanup Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177182.aspx)" which you can set up to delete all backups of a certain database *older than X*.

[Here is a blog post](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/BradSchacht/ssis/249/sql-maintenance-plan-doesn-t-delete-backups) that describes a common gotcha, but also shows the Maintenance Cleanup Task with the necessary settings.

Comment: It seems like there isn't the ability to, say, control how many backups are kept for a particular database (which is unfortunate..).  Thank you, though!  Quite helpful..

Comment: @Mani5556: No, as far as I know you can't specify a *number* of backups to keep. But why would you want to do this? If you create a backup, say, once a day, and you setup the cleanup task to delete everything older than X days, you know exactly how many backups you are keeping.

Comment: We will only be performing backups when the end user's database is updated, so not necessarily creating 1/day.

Comment: Okay, that's really a special case. How do you trigger the backup "when the end user's database is updated"? Do you start it manually? And do you want to keep the last *X* backups or do you just want to delete **every** old backup each time you make a new one? If you want the latter, you can do it with the Cleanup Task by simply not checking the "Delete files based on the age..." checkbox.

Comment: We trigger a database update whenever we release an application update, so it might be once every month, maybe not: theres no concrete schedule.  I want to keep the latest 3 backups (to be specific) - was thinking could write a custom SQLCLR to do it, potentially..  but I was hoping there was an easier way

Comment: Nothing out-of-the box that I know of. I'm afraid you have to write that yourself.

Comment: Figured as much.  Thanks for the insights.

Answer (score 1):

As Christian said, maintenance plans don't support your scenario. And server-side code (TSQL or CLR procedures) often becomes very awkward when you need to interact with the filesystem.

So this is probably easiest to do at the OS level. Back up each database to a separate folder using a maintenance plan or some other method, then write a script in Perl, PowerShell or whatever you like that deletes the oldest file(s) from the folder when there are more than 3 files present. You can schedule it to run once per hour, day, week or whatever fits your release schedule.